# How to show an array (multiple values) in a webix datatable column

Tags: datatable, webix

I need to show multiple values (rank and vote) together separated by space as key:value in a webix  datatable cell from the following structure :

id2: [{"rank":2, "vote":50}, {"rank":3, "vote":10}]

I want to show only the first element of this above array.

My snippet is here : https://webix.com/snippet/ca50874d

I am not able to figure out how to show these two values together in one cell.
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: From this link https://docs.webix.com/datatable__data_mapping.html , I could only figure out that to show the first element of the array object , I can use map attribute as below : 
{ id:"id2", header:"Rank", width:80, map:"#id2[0]#", 
tempplate:"rank:#rank# vote:#vote#"}, however, not sure how to show the rank and vote of the object. Any help would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show multiple values in the cell, or if you want to format the value according to you, you just need to use to template for that cell:

While specifying column configuration, you can specify the template for that particular column like below:

`template:function(obj) {
}`

This template will be called for each row, and obj contains the row object.
For your example you can specify the template like below:

`template:function(obj) {
       return obj.column1 +':' + obj.column2;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I further tried and could figure out the answer on my own. To show the first element of that array object, the 'map' attribute has to be used as below:

```
  { id:"id2",     header:"Rank",    width:80, map:"#id2[0].rank# : #id2[0].vote# "}
```

The working snippet for the same is here : https://webix.com/snippet/928bab77